# How do I sketch the PDF for this transformation of a uniform variable?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Suppose X~unif(0,1) Determine and sketch Y = 1/X.

I got the PDF of Y: $y^{-2}*f_x[1/y]$

But I am lost on how to sketch this. Is it simply that X goes from 0 to 1, so Y goes from infinity to 0? What does it mean when Y goes from a bigger number to smaller number (backwards)? Still I'm not sure how to plot the PDF of this.

Comment: Yes first of all you should workout the support of $Y$ - Given $x \in (0, 1)$, what is the range of $y = 1/x$? Next you should try to sketch the function $y = x^{-2}$ on that range. If you have seen some hyperbola before then you should have no problem. If not you just follow the standard method for graph sketching - evaluate the derivative to determine when do it increase/decrease; and then calculate some special points like the end points, limits, asymptotes, and second derivative for inflection point etc.

Comment: @BGM Thanks, maybe i'm overcomplicating this. But I am lost on how to calculate $f_x(1/y)$. How do I plot that part?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the transformation formula to get the pdf of Y:

$$f_Y(y)=\left|\frac{dg^{-1}(y)}{dy} \right|\cdot f_X(g^{-1}(y))$$

The result is $y^{-2}$.

You get the  same since $f_X\left( \frac1y \right)=1$

You are right that the support of  Y is $(1,\infty)$. But it does not mean that it goes somehow backwards. The cdf for instance is $F_X(x)=P(X\leq x)$. This would´t work if the domain would be something like $(\infty, 1)$. I think you are able to plot the pdf.

---

At the beginning the (negative) slope is relative large. Conequently it is a good idea to make smaller steps at the beginning.

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|} \hline y&1&1.1&1.2&1.3&1.4&1.5&2&3&4 \\ \hline  1/y^2&1&0.82 &0.69&0.59&0.51&0.44&0.25&0.11&0.063 \\ \hline \end{array}$$

The sketch should look like [image]

Comment: Why is $f_x(1/y) = 1?$ How would I plot $f_x?$

Comment: $f_X(x)=1, 0<x<1$ . It is always 1 regardless what $x$ is. Sketching the pdf: You just have to sketch $\frac{1}{y^2}$. Make a table for some values. And also note that $\lim_{ y\to  \infty} f_Y(y)=0$ . I have made an edit of my answer.

Comment: That is interesting. When doing such a variable transformation, is the PDF of the new variable always going to be equivalent to 1 when it is a uniform distribution?